# Different notation for Jacobi symbol

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, notation

Is there a different, *sort of* established, notation for the Legendre / Jacobi / Kronecker symbol $\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)$? If yes, where is it used (in which texts)?

I'm asking, because I personally think the notation is absolutely terrible and I really dislike using it in my own notes.

(The notation obviously conflicts with fractions, especially if functions are applied to them, like: $\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!$ or $\mu(\frac{a}{p})$)

Comment: sure is lonely here...